# HIghlight UITableViewCell with image

Tags: ios, uitableview

In my app I am using UITableView. I want to highlight cell with an image. 
My code is:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [slideMenuTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected_tab_bg.png"]];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = image;
}
```

It highlights the cell but when I select another cell previous cell is also selected as shown below. I want to clear the previous cell when i select another cell[image: screen shot]

In the screen shot List view and Search are highlighted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cellForRowAtImagePath may send you a recycled cell, which may or may not be your previously highlighted cell.  If you've set a cell to highlighted, then you need to remember that cell, and unset it.  Alternatively, you could have an if condition in cellForRowAtImagePath, and make sure it unsets a previously highlighted and sets a currently highlighted according to the current indexPath, then call reloadData on the tableview to make it redraw everything.

Comment: Yes i did it. Thanks Owen

Answer (score 1):

Like didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [slideMenuTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected_tab_bg.png"]];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = image;
    }
```

There is another delegate method named, `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`

Write this code over there:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
cell.selectedBackgroundView = nil; // or set anything else like normal cell
}
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.